# Is it possible to remove the audio prompt that Transfer to queue always plays? - contact flow - amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Was just wondering if anybody has hit this same problem. I'm using the Transfer to Queue block in my Contact flow to of course transfer the call to another queue where there is always an available "agent" who will always pick up the phone (trying to mimmic a voicemail system). I would like the customer not to know they are being transferred to another queue but the Transfer to queue block always prompt an audio saying "You call is very valuable for us and will be answered.....".

Any ideas on how to get rid of that? No configuration option from the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the Customer Queue Contact Flow that is set for the call, what you’re hearing is the default Customer Queue Contact Flow. You can customize the behavior, by creating a new Customer Queue Contact Flow and assigning that to be used by the call. You must set the Customer Queue flow using the appropriate Set block in your main Contact Flow before hitting the Transfer to Queue block or it will use the default flow that you’re hearing now.

The different types of Contact Flow are explained in the Amazon Connect documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/userguide/contactflow.html)